# Access insert multiple rows into SSMS

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a table in access and I am trying to insert all the rows into a table in SSMS.

This is the data that I have in the Access form.  I have it working in Access where it inserts the first row.

```
PONumber  RollNumber    ItemNumber
123       A20           COFFEESLV.2
123       A21           COFFEESLV.2
123       A23           COFFEESLV.2
```

Access calls a stored procedure and

```
INSERT INTO Receipts 
(   
      PONumber
    , ItemNumber
    , RollNumber
)
Values
(   
    @PONumber   --PONumber  (These get passed in from the Access Form.(
    ,@Item      --ItemNumber
    ,'1'        --RollNumber (I'm using this for testing. It works. But now it 
                 needs to insert all of them. There could be up to 100.
)
```

How do I get it to insert all the rows in the table? The table itself is also in SSMS.  It is just a table that holds the values of the rolls of coffee sleeves until we receipt them, and then the values get deleted.

ETA - I think my problem is that the Temp table only contains the Roll Numbers.   The form contains fields for the rest of the information.  So I can't do a simple insert into select from the two tables right in SSMS.  I don't know how to get the Temp table to grab the fields from the subform (I think it's a subform, but its not connected to anything.  I tried to get that to work but could not.)

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you use a bound form? Then all your date will be stored in a table and you can transfer your data to SSMS.

Comment: As @Rene suggets, enter data to table then perhaps INSERT SELECT will satisfy requirement: https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_insert_into_select.asp. However, instead of query object, use VBA to construct the INSERT SELECT and concatenate references to form controls. Then run the SQL with CurrentDb.Execute.

Comment: Just noticed your query is a stored procedure. Since I've never used, can only guess that the INSERT SELECT could be structured in the procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you.

I did an insert into select in the procedure.  I passed in the values that I needed from the form.  On the form there was a subform attached to an SSMS table.

So my insert looked like

```
Insert Into MyTable (Number, Color, Size, Price)
Select Number, Color, Size, @Price
From SubfrmTable
```

You can just throw in a passed down variable right in the insert into select (@Price). I didn't know that.  Hopefully this will help others.